# WSO2 APIM Test API on publisher portal fails due to CORS

Tags: spring-boot, cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have REST API's in a java springboot application deployed on Istio and exposed via WSO2 APIM.
For the already existing API's that were published, the API's work perfectly fine. But for an API that I am trying to expose via WSO2 for the first time, I get the CORS error along with a 404 Error -

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Inspecting network tab -

Access to fetch at 'https://host:8243/test/book/v1/api/v1/book/category' from origin 'https://host:9443' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

On inspecting the network tab found the missing CORS headers that allow origins, methods and headers different from that in the working API in the Response header

Note - All runtime and policy configurations of the API are similar to the working API's.

The only notable difference here is that I have not yet published my API, and there are no subscription, as I wanted to test the API first before publishing it.

The backend code has a Cors Filter that adds the required headers, however the Filter class is placed in a sub package in the non-working API, whereas its present at the controller level in the working API. Could the placement of the Filter have an impact on the responses?

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Any help would be humbly appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved simply by restarting the docker container with WSO2 APIM. command - docker restart <container_id>
Apparently for the changes of the new API to take effect, it needed a restart, we did that and were able to successfully try out our API's from the publisher portal as well as the subscriber portal
thanks!